# Client request JSON through JS and populate Rails view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want that my user(through his browser) make a request to an API(that returns JSON) and that the result populate a view in my Rails(4.2) app. I don't want my app making the requests, only the user.

That behaviour will happen quite often so I am looking for a better solution than Jquery + inserting directly on HTML.

Maybe one template engine would help, was trying Handlebars(tilt+tilt-handlebars) but without success.

To make it easy, what would be the best way to do this ?

### Should be:

- easy to get data from API, with Jquery or not. Or at least easy to insert the data in the template
- easy way to work with the data as Handlebars "each" `{{#each objects}} {{/#each}}`
- easy to insert data into html if not able to do it through the template engine
- work with Rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like you are talking about [Angular](https://angularjs.org/).
There is a lot of resources for this combination [link](http://www.angularonrails.com/ruby-on-rails-angularjs-single-page-application/)
I suggest Yeoman for scaffolding your app.

Comment: Angular seems to be a great choice. Was looking for something more like a template engine only. But it works. I am using Rails, Yeoman wouldn't help me.